# Can someone check I changed the date of git commits?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository

I created a private repository in github where, in every commit, I changed my local computer datetime (just by changing the date and time in Windows bottom right task bar) and then do:

```
git commit --amend --date=now
git push
```

For example, I made a commit changing my date to "04/07/20". When I run `git log` (using `--pretty=fuller`), I can check that the AuthorDate and CommitDate are the ones I had in my local computer:

```
AuthorDate: Wed Apr 7 12:51:13 2020 -0300
CommitDate: Wed Apr 7 12:51:13 2020 -0300
```

My question is: after doing this commits by changing my local computer datetime, can someone verify I changed those dates somehow and see the actual real date they were committed?
Also, can someone see the date the repo was created?

Thank you

Comment: Note that if you're doing forensic analysis—e.g., to break someone's alibi ("I could not have committed that murder, I was committing a file at work")—you could prove that *some* timestamp is corrupt if, e.g., commit P (parent) has timestamp T and commit C (child) has timestamp T-k for some positive integer k. But you don't know if it's P or C that's wrong here. BTW: how are you at -0300? In Brazil or Argentina? Greenland?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the date of a commit, you don't actually have to change the date of your computer.  You can simply set `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`, which will set those values.  The exception is if you're signing your commits, in which case GnuPG will insert the current time, and in some cases (e.g., with S/MIME), it's possible it may embed an external timestamp.

Assuming you're not signing your commits, there's no way to tell from the repository contents when the commit was made.  It may be possible for someone to use the GitHub API to determine when a particular revision was pushed, but as long as your fake timestamp is before that date, it wouldn't be provable that it was falsified.

As you can see in [the REST API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos), GitHub does log when a repository was created, updated, and pushed.

Comment: Thank you! One question: if the repository is private, can someone use the Github API to determine these things?

Comment: One more thing: how do I set the GIT_AUTHOR_DATE and GIT_COMMITTER_DATE variables?

Comment: I believe that information is accessible via the API for folks that have read access to the repository.  `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`  are environment variables whose valid values are documented in the `git-commit(1)` manual page, and in a POSIX shell, you can simply preface your command with them: `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=now git commit --amend`.

Answer (score 2):

This might help ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-dates?view=azure-devops.)):

> Author date: when a commit was originally authored. Typically, when someone first ran git commit.
>
> Commit date: when a commit was applied to the branch. In many cases it is the same as the author date. Sometimes it differs: if a commit was amended, rebased, or applied by someone other than the author as part of a patch. In those cases, the date will be when the rebase happened or the patch was applied.
>
> Push date: when a commit was pushed to the remote repository in question. This date is specific to the remote version control system you are using, and won't be available in your local repository.

If someone checked your push date they would know if you modified the dat. from what I've seen, however, the push date cannot be (easily) collected from git. Otherwise, I have not seen any way for someone to see the true dates.

I've seen that it's possible to get a repository's creation date by finding the first commit to the repository. It's also possible to find the the repo's creation date by using techniques as suggested in [How to know the creation date of GitHub repository](https://mycyberuniverse.com/how-know-creation-date-github-repository.html). (Note: Github's website doesn't display a repo's creation date.)